# EACCESS permission denied, while trying to add jquery.min.js into angular-cli.json

Tags: jquery, angularjs, json, npm, permission-denied

I did npm install on my angular project to add bootstrap,jquery and tether via terminal, had no errors. But when i try to edit the angular-cli.json file to add the scripts i receive the eaccess error : Failed to save '.angular-cli.json': A system error occurred (EACCES: permission denied, open '/home/kmx/angular/projetos/passaroUrbano/.angular-cli.json').

Any ideas how to fix this?

```
    "scripts": [
    "../node_modules/tether/dist/js/tether.min.js",
    "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"

  ],
```

Comment: Solved...with CHMOD 777 ../.angular-cli.json

Comment: Advice to other SO users `chmod 777` is a very dangerous security setting. Please use it only if you know the consequences.